# What type of contractor do I need for ventilation and ducts?

Tags: contractors

I'm trying to be my own GC. What type of contractors do I need to install range hood and the necessary venting?  They would also need to help do the venting for a clothes dryer.

Comment: Any decent carpenter can do the cutting and fitting of the ductwork.  If you don't have electrical feeds to the range hood, then you'll want an electrician to pull wiring for you.

Comment: I agree+ range hoods and dryer vents are easily installed by many home owners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Heating, Ventilation, Refrigeration, and Air Conditioning (HVAC) technician, should be able to handle the vents.  If there's electrical involved, you'll need an Electrician for that portion of the work. Though some HVAC companies may be able to handle the whole job.

If you don't want to dish out for an HVAC tech, you could likely handle it yourself with the purchase of a few hand tools. Specifically, you'll want a set of [aviation snips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006FC8U7M) (left, right, and straight), and a [5 blade crimping tool](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002RI8ZA).  [Duct seal mastics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0085UZBE2) are all the rage, though a quality foil tape should work just fine.

If that doesn't appeal to you either, any local "handyman" should be able to do the vent work. Just make sure the person is licensed, insured, and registered with the [Better Business Bureau®](https://www.bbb.org/) or some other similar organization.